# Facebook "like" button multilanguage

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, localisation, facebook

After trying a lot of extensions, I've ended up uninstalling all the extensions and add the social buttons by myself via code.

Apparently I managed to create the buttons correctly (altough the Facebook button takes a HUGE amount of sec. to load) but I'm struggling to have these buttons automatically trnaslated in other language.

My website has 2 languages (and store views), but I can not find how to swap the button text and the social popup content for sharing automatically.

So, now the trouble is:

I have the FB "like" button in Italian, when I change store view for English I still have the FB "like" button (and the content of the FB box for sharing the product) in Italian.

Is it possible to change this?

#### This is the code inside the file "view.phtml":

```
 <div id="facebook_like_product_button"><fb:like ref="product_page" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" colorscheme="light" width="500"></fb:like></div>

<!-- Facebook Like Product Button BEGIN - load the SDK asynchronously -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script>
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({appId: '1386792571543845', status: true, cookie: true,
                xfbml: true});
        };
        (function() {
            var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo $this->__('it_IT') ?>/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
        }());
         /* ]]> */
        </script>
<!-- Facebook Like Product Button END -->
```

I tried to replace

```
<?php echo $this->__('it_IT') ?>
```

with :

```
<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>
```

But the fb button disappears.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a custom block, for example:

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Block_Facebook extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('company/module/facebook.phtml');
    }

    public function getScheme()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure() ? 'https:' : 'http:';
    }

    public function getLocale()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_LOCALE);
    }
}
```

And in `company/module/facebook.phtml` template:

```
<div id="facebook_like_product_button"><fb:like ref="product_page" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" colorscheme="light" width="500"></fb:like></div>

<!-- Facebook Like Product Button BEGIN - load the SDK asynchronously -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '1386792571543845', status: true, cookie: true,
            xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '<?php echo $this->getScheme() ?>' +
        '//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo $this->getLocale() ?>/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    /* ]]> */
</script>
<!-- Facebook Like Product Button END -->
```

You can then insert your block via layout update.

Comment: thank you !
Just one last question: assuming my lack of knowledge in magento there is another simplier way to do that? 
I know that editing the code is nto a "best practice" and will have collateral effects during magento updates, but if I do not need (or want ) to update , what could be the fastest way?
If I simply modify my code in the view.phtml page using :<?php echo $this->getLocale() ?> insted of  <?php echo $this->__('it_IT') ?> what should I add more? and in what file? thank you very much and please excuse me for the bother.